# Microsoft Graph API - How to Delete a Folder with Children

Tags: azure, rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I could use some help deleting a folder using the Microsoft Graph API.  The api call below works, but only when the folder is empty and has no children.

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{{driveId}}/items/{{driveItemId}}
```

1. The folders are created and deleted using the same client application and permissions
2. It's a folder in a Sharepoint document library if that matters at all
3. I tried adding an `If-Match` header with the current eTag of the folder, but that didn't make any difference.

Here's the response I'm getting:

```
409 Conflict
{
    "error": {
        "code": "resourceModified",
        "message": "The resource has changed since the caller last read it; usually an eTag mismatch",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-10-17T21:40:30",
            "request-id": "b3d35695-...",
            "client-request-id": "b3d35695-..."
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to force the delete, or do I have to clear it out before I can delete it?  If I have to clear it out, what's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one Azure AD application and granted **`API permissions`** like below:

[image]

To call Microsoft Graph, I acquired **access token** using client credentials flow via **Postman** as below:

[image]

I created folder in my **SharePoint document library** using above token with below **query**:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<driveID>/items/
{
"name": "Sri Folder",
"folder": { },
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked in **SharePoint Online**, folder created successfully in document library like below:

[image]

Now I added **children** to the created **`folder`** by uploading one file to it with below query:

```json
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<driveID>/items/<driveItemId>:/test.txt:/content
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in **SharePoint Online**, file is uploaded to the folder successfully like below:

[image]

Now, I used the **same query** as you to delete the folder with children by adding **`If-match`** header and got **same** error like below:

```json
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<driveId>/items/<driveItemId>
If-match : etag_value
```

**Response**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to replace **`If-match`** header with **`eTag`**.

I tried the same query by replacing **`If-match`** header with **`eTag`**, it returned **Status: 204 No Content** like below:

**Response:**

[image]

When I refreshed the page in **SharePoint Online**, got this error as folder got **deleted** along with its children:

[image]

I checked opening ***document library*** and cannot find the **folder** as it got deleted successfully:

[image]

Comment: The `eTag` header did the trick!  Thanks so much @Sridevi.

Answer (score 0):

**First get token:**

```
TOKEN=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
        -d "client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default" \
        https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token | \
        python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['access_token'])")
```

**Second get driver id:**

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${TENANT_NAME}.sharepoint.com:/sites/${SITE_NAME}

curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${SITE_ID}/drive
```

**Third Delete using the path:**

```
curl -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \       
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/${DRIVE_ID}/root:/Borrar/BOLIVIA/MAS.jpg
```